# custom post type not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress, post, types

I have made a custom post type called `movies` and added a movie meta box with some options I would like to see on my post about the movie I am adding to my archive.

The problem is I can get it to view all the meta info in one post but not the specific meta info for the one movie I am looking at in `single-movie.php`

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="panel panel-default panel-body">

    <p class="fa fa-calendar"></p>&nbsp;<?php the_time('d-m-Y'); ?> | <p class="fa fa-clock-o"></p> <?php the_time('H:i a'); ?> |&nbsp;<p class="fa fa-user"></p>&nbsp;<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></i> |&nbsp;<p class="fa fa-envelope-o"></p>&nbsp;posted in movies

<article class="post <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>has-thumbnail <?php } ?> clearfix">

    <article class="post-thumbnail">

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('image-poster'); ?></a>

    </article>

    <article class="post-thumbnail-text">

        <h4 class="align_Center" style="color:#000; padding-bottom:1em;"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>

        <?php $posts = get_posts(array(
            'post_type'   => 'movies',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'fields' => 'ids'
            )
        );

            $nam = get_post_meta( $posts, "name", true );
            $rel = get_post_meta( $posts, "released", true );
            $rat = get_post_meta( $posts, "rating", true );
            $dur = get_post_meta( $posts, "duration", true );
            $gen = get_post_meta( $posts, "genrer", true );
            $dir = get_post_meta( $posts, "director", true );
            $wri = get_post_meta( $posts, "writer", true );
            $sta = get_post_meta( $posts, "stars", true );
            $sto = get_post_meta( $posts, "storyline", true );

            ?>

            <div class="align_Left">
                <p>Title:</p>&nbsp;<?php echo $nam; ?><br>
                <p>Released:</p>&nbsp;<?php echo $rel; ?><br>
                <p>Rating:</p>&nbsp;<?php echo $rat; ?><br>
                <p>Duration:</p>&nbsp;<?php echo $dur; ?><br>
                <p>Genre:</p>&nbsp;<?php echo $gen; ?><br>
                <p>Director:</p>&nbsp;<?php echo $dir; ?><br>
                <p>Writer:</p>&nbsp;<?php echo $wri; ?><br>
                <p>Stars:</p>&nbsp;<?php echo $sta; ?><br>
                <p>Storyline:</p>&nbsp;<?php echo $sto; ?>
            </div>

    </article>

</article>

</div>

<?php endwhile;

else :

    echo '<p>NO CONTENT FOUND</p>';

endif; ?>

</div><!-- ./CONTAINER --> 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_posts()` return array of posts no only one post. `get_post_meta()` for first parameter needs id of single post not array of posts' ids.

What you need to do is create loop for example:

```
foreach ( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
  $name = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "name", true ); ?>
  ...
  <p>Title:</p>&nbsp;<?php echo $nam; ?><br>
  ...
<?php
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: all I need to do now is figure out the full list rather than the single lol cheers m8

Comment: Using loop you'll generate full list.

Comment: in movies.php or ? sorry I'm a bit of an amateur :(

Comment: `$posts = get_posts(array('post_type'   => 'movies','post_status' => 'publish','posts_per_page' => -1,'fields' => 'ids'));` you use this function in your code. It create array of all movies ids into $posts variable. To print all of them you have to use loop. Try code I've posted above

Comment: I understand about the loop and I had a loop before but it output all info of all movie metadata in one movie post. so what file Is it I change plz. sorry for being a noobie :)